# How can I underline a Heading element finitely while keeping it in the center(using text-align) at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-web-developer

I want to underline my  element finitely while keeping it in center of the page using text-align: center. However, using border-bottom(for underline) and text-align: center at the same time, the underline goes on till the end of the page. Is there any other way I can achieve this?
Hope you understand my issue. Thanks in advance.

```css
  h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  color: #353935;
  border-bottom: 4px double black;
```

```html
<h1>Heading Text</h1>
```

Kalpana Chawla is the content of my  element. As you can see, the underline starts well before 'K' and ends afar from 'a'. I want the underline to start just from K' and end at 'a' while keeping the heading in the center.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. We need to see some HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope this is you are looking for,
use **`text-decoration: underline`**

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  color: #353935;
  text-decoration: underline double;
  }
```

```html
<h1>Heading Text</h1>
```

Comment: my bad, i saw you answer pretty good. 

Comment: text-decoration: underline double; works. Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: that is new for me, thanks  
@AbhishekRathore

Answer (score 2):

You could make the heading inline-block and center it in a container element.

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  color: #353935;
  border-bottom: 4px double black;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <h1>Heading Text</h1>
</div>
```